# SQLAlchemy 1.4 abstracting MetaData.reflect into function not returning MetaData object?

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-3.7, database-metadata

I have a class that acts as a PostgreSQL database interface. It has a number of methods which do things with the `MetaData`, such as get table names, drop tables, etc.
These methods keep calling the same two lines to set up `MetaData`. I am trying to tidy this up by abstracting this `MetaData` setup into its own function which is initiated when the class is instantiated, but this isn't working, as the function keeps returning `NoneType` instead of the `MetaData` instance.

Here is an example of the class, BEFORE adding the `MetaData` function:

```
class Db:

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.engine = create_async_engine(ENGINE, echo=True, future=True)
        self.session = sessionmaker(self.engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)

    def get_table_names(self):
        meta = MetaData()
        meta.reflect(bind=sync_engine)
        meta = self.meta()
        return meta.tables.keys()
```

This works well, returns a list of table keys:

```
dict_keys(['user', 'images', 'session'])
```

When I try to shift the `MetaData` call into its own function like so:

```
class Db:

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.engine = create_async_engine(ENGINE, echo=True, future=True)
        self.session = sessionmaker(self.engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)
        self.meta = self.get_metadata()
    
    def get_metadata(self):
        meta = MetaData()
        return meta.reflect(bind=sync_engine)

    def get_table_names(self):
        return self.meta.tables.keys()
```

It returns this error:

```
in get_table_names  return self.meta.tables.keys()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tables'
```

How can I achieve this sort of functionality by calling self.meta() from within the various class methods?

Answer (score 2):

Reflect alters the current metadata in-place.  So you can just return the `meta` variable explicitly.

```py
class Db:
    # ...

    def get_metadata(self):
        meta = MetaData()
        meta.reflect(bind=sync_engine)
        return meta
    
    # ...
```

Although it might be better to do this in a factory function, like `def db_factory(config):` and inject these things already prepped in the class constructor, `def __init__(self, metadata, engine, session):`.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I ended up doing something similar to this, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post an answer, as with someone else's help I was able to solve this. The code should look like this:

class Db:

```
def __init__(self, config):
    self.engine = create_async_engine(ENGINE, echo=True, future=True)
    self.session = sessionmaker(self.engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)
    self._meta = MetaData()

@property
def meta(self):
    self._meta.reflect(bind=sync_engine)
    return self._meta

def get_table_names(self):
    return self.meta.tables.keys()
```